# Do I need to install Drupal using Drush in order to use Drush?

Tags: drush

I installed Drush and then I installed Drupal using the regular installer/method.

When I type `drush cc all` on my terminal I get this message:

> No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, you do not need to install Drupal using Drush in order to use Drush. All you need is to make sure that while running `drush cc all`, you are in the Drupal directory.

For example, if your Drupal lies under `/var/www/Projects` with root name as `drupal` then first you need to move inside `/var/www/Projects/drupal` and then run the `drush cc all` command.

**The reason being, Drush can be executed inside a Drupal environment only.**

Comment: Technically Drush can be executed outside of a Drupal environment. Most commands such as enabling module and clearing site cache need to be in Drupal environment.  Though "drush cc drush" will clear the drush cache no matter where you are. This needs to be done if you downloaded a new drush extension.

Also "drush dl" can be run anywhere, for instance to download Drupal itself.

Comment: right, for anything you need to make database connection for example enabling a drupal module, you have to run it with in drupal env.

Answer (score 1):

No, drush is independent of each drupal install.  But you need to run the command from within the project root, or using a drush alias.

To test if drush is picking up your site properly, you can run

```
drush st
```

This will output information about your site, or will let you know if you are not within a site.

If you are connected, you should see database information like this:

```
 Database username               :  root                                              
 Database name                   :  mydatebasename                                      
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
```

Then your cache clear will work with

```
drush cc all
```

If you run

```
drush st
```

from outside of a drupal project, it will not show the database information.